# Duplicate links

Tags: zend-framework, seo

I have a question regarding Zend_Framework and urls.

If I have a controller `CategoriesController.php` and the action is call `products`. I rewrite my link so now I can access the product page like this: `www.mysite.com/see-products`.

So now I access this page in 2 ways:

- (the classic zend way: controller/action) `www.mysite.com/categories/products`

and

- (the way I rewrite the link) `www.mysite.com/see-products`

The question is: the page is consider duplicate and what can I do about this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable default routes:

```
Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getRouter()->removeDefaultRoutes();
```